# Select account from list, run macro, save, select next account and repeat until list complete

Tags: vba, list, random, offset

Running a macro, I want a cell to be updated with the next account number and rerun the macro. In 1 instance went to 2nd account in list. But the following is not working. Any suggestions?

```vb
Sub my_sub()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
 Set ws = Worksheets("summary")  'ws with list of fund numbers
 Set rng = ws.Range("L7")       '1st row with fund numbers
 
 Range("LIST") = rng
 
 Do Until IsEmpty(rng)
 
    Call runitallpls
 
    Set Range("rng") = rng.Offset(1, 0)
 
    'Select next fund number by stepping down 1 row from list
 
 Loop
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcom to Stack Overflow. Your question and your code example are not clear enough to help you. Please read [ask] and [its not working](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) - both should help you to improve your question. Furthermore: always use explicit range references otherwise the result of your code is depending on the active sheet that might change any time (--> `Range("LIST")`. And propably reading some tutorials about the range/cell objects in VBA might help you too.

Comment: Post an image of your sheet ``As Is`` and another ``To be``.